# How to track set locationManager.delegate the right way?

Tags: ios, swift, location, core-location

I tried to use CoreLocation with Swift to track the user's location:

*(Below you can find the code of may ViewController.swift file.*)

But the code doesn't seems working as I've expected, because I'm still getting the **same error** every-time I'm launching the application:

[image: Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'CLLocationManagerDelegate?']

I'm sure this is the problem why I'm not able to get a result from the `locationManager()` function that should print out the current location.

It says `"Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'CLLocationManagerDelegate?'"`

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation 

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        print("CLLocationManager is available")
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
  }

  let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.first {
        print(location.coordinate)
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone now how to fix this problem? - Any help would be very appreciated, thanks a million in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply need to declare conformance to `CLLocationManagerDelegate`. You can either do this directly in the class declaration just as you did with `WKUIDelegate` or in an extension of `ViewController`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            print("CLLocationManager is available")
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.first {
            print(location.coordinate)
        }
    }
}
```

With extension:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            print("CLLocationManager is available")
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.first {
            print(location.coordinate)
        }
    }
}
```